# Setting axis to log with pyplot

Tags: matplotlib

When I'm trying to set the axis to log with  plt.xscale('log') the scale runs from 10^-2 to 10^-3, how can I change this range? I've tried setting plt.axis([0,1e5,0,1e13]) before but then I get a warning that I'm converting a masked elemented to nan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim`, for example:

```
plt.xlim([1,1e5])
plt.ylim([1,1e13])
```

(remember you can't have 0 on a log scale)